# Spring Boot JPA/JDBC batching findById works but findOneByX not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring Boot JPA, I have enabled batching by ensuring the following lines are in the my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

I now have a loop where I am doing a findById on an entity and then saving that entity like so:

```
var entity = dao.findById(id)
// Do some stuff
dao.save(entity) //This line is not really required but I am being explicit here
```

Putting the above in a loop I see that the save(update) statements are batched to the DB.
My issue is that if I do a findOneByX where X is a property on the entity then the batching does not work (batch size of 1), requests get sent one at a time i.e.:

```
var entity = dao.findOneByX(x)
// Do some stuff
dao.save(entity)
```

Why is this happening? Is JPA/JDBC only equipped to batch when we findById only?

Comment: This is how JPA works. When a query is issued, pending changes will first be flushed to the database before executing the query. That way you will have a consistent result. You could disable auto-flushing for this part, but then you might get inconsistent result from your find query (depending on what you do with that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Refer to [How to implement batch update using Spring Data Jpa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462221/how-to-implement-batch-update-using-spring-data-jpa#answer-62675040)

1. Fetch the list of entity you want to update to a list
2. Update as desired
3. Call [`saveAll`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-)

PS: beware of memory usage for this solution, when your list size is large.

---

#### Why `findById` and `findOneByX` behave differently?

As suggested by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum), [hibernate will auto flush](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto) your change

> prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued entity actions

Since both `findById` and `findOneByX` will execute query, what is the different between them?

First, the reason to flush is to make sure session and Database are in same state, hence you can get consistent result from session cache(if available) and database.

When calling `findById`, hibernate will try to get it from session cache, if entity is not available, fetch it from database. While for `findOneByX`, we always need to fetch it from database as it is impossible to cache entity by X.

Then we can consider below example:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Suppose we have

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amy | 10 |

```
@Transactional
public void findByIdAndUpdate() {
    dao.save(new Student(2L, "Dennis", 14));
    // no need to flush as we can get from session
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Student dennis = dao.findById(2L).orElseThrow();
        dennis.setAge(i);
        dao.save(dennis);
    }
}
```

Will result in

> ```
> 412041 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC batches;
> ```

1 for insert 1 one for update.

- Hibernate: I'm sure that result can be fetch from session (without flush) or database if record is not in session, so let's skip flushing as it is slow!

```
@Transactional
public void findOneByNameAndUpdate() {
    Student amy = dao.findOneByName("Amy");
    // this affect later query
    amy.setName("Tammy");
    dao.save(amy);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // do you expect getting result here?
        Student tammy = dao.findOneByName("Tammy");
        // Hibernate not smart enough to notice this will not affect later result.
        tammy.setAge(i);
        dao.save(tammy);
    }
}
```

Will result in

> ```
> 13964088 nanoseconds spent executing 101 JDBC batches;
> ```

1 for first update and 100 for update in loop.

- Hibernate: Hmm, I'm not sure if stored update will affect the result, better flush the update or I will be blamed by developer.

Comment: Right but in the case above which executed in 412041 nanoseconds, if you remove the save from outside the loop and iterate over multiple elements doing a findById (i.e. 100 elements with a findById) this still only results in 1 update BATCH of size 100 and 100 select batches of size 1. 
I was more after why doing a findByX which should be a select results in 100 update batches of size 1 and 100 select batches of size 1.
In the first case I mention in this comment there is still a fetch to the DB but the update is sent all in 1 batch but this is not happening in the second case.

Comment: In the example `findOneByNameAndUpdate`, the update need to be flushed to database when calling `dao.findOneByName`. otherwise `dao.findOneByName("Tammy")` will return no result.